# How To Delay Button Action Until Transition ends in JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a button With a Hover Animation. This button redirects to another page. Whenever I click on the Button. The redirect action Happens immediately Before the transition Even Starts. How can I delay the action until the transition ends? Iam Using

```
window.location.href = ""
```

To do The Redirect Action

Comment: Redirect after having detected that he animation has ended. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using CSS transition and you can wait for the `animateend` callback [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event).

Perhaps there is an easy way to do this, calculate/figure out how much time is taking to complete the transition and wait that time with a `timeout`.

You may try something line this:

```js
function btnClicked() {
    setTimeout(
        function() {
            window.location.href = "";
        }, 
        500  // suppose, your transition take 500ms to complete
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably the simplest would be to just delay the redirection in time, and adjust delay time to how long your animation takes:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = ""; }, 3000);
```